# Reset Bash's memory used for auto-complete

Tags: bash, osx, autocomplete, cache

After renaming a file to a similar name, I noticed TAB was still completing the old filename (if it matched the letters so far) and not showing the new one. No matter how many letters I typed, it refused to complete the new name.

I fixed it simply by starting a new shell. All good, but I'm still curious about what happened.

I assume Bash is caching the file strings somewhere and the cache had failed to refresh/clear itself when the file had been renamed. Is my assumption correct, and if so, how could the cache be auto-refreshed?

Comment: Bash doesn't cache filenames internally, unless you have some funky bash completion from somewhere else that's doing it. Were you just doing `x/y/z`, or `some_command x/y/z`? I think it's much more likely that it could be a third party bash completion doing it judging by the description.

Comment: Ah yes, I had recently installed https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash. Must be it.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently installed [git completion](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash.) which does some caching. I'll need to look in more detail but anyway, it does cache, so that's the cause here.

Comment: Did you ever resolve how to clear the cache?